# Product functor and diagonal functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

> Let $C$ be a category and consider the product category $C \times C$.  There is a diagonal functor associating to each object $X$ of $C$ the pair $(X,X)$ as an object of $C \times C$.  On the other hand, there may be a product functor $C \times C \rightarrow C$, associating to $(X,Y)$ a product $X \times Y$.  For example, this is the case in $Grp$.  Convince yourself that the product functor is right-adjoint to the diagonal functor.  If there is a coproduct functor, verify that it is left-adjoint to the diagonal functor. (Aluffi, *Algebra: Chapter $0$*, Chapter 8, Exercise 1.22)

What does it mean here a diagonal functor, left-adjoint, right-adjoint, and what does the diagram look like and how to start this problem.

Comment: It sounds as if you need to look at a category THeory text. I recall folks recommending "Categories for the working mathematician" back in the 1980s; I assume it's still a fine book.

Comment: "Diagonal functor" is just the name for the functor defined in objects by $X\mapsto (X,X)$ and similarly on morphisms, which is described at the beginning of your quote. As for left and right adjoint, I'm sure that Allufi defines these terms. Have you reviewed their definitions?

Comment: Aluffi defines left and right adjoints on p.492, right below the definition of natural transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading a book on Category Theory, such as [Steve Awodey's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199237182), for instance. Aluffi is excellent for seeing category theoretic language in its natural algebraic setting, but I find he can gloss over some concepts a bit quickly. Tom Leinster also has an excellent (and free!) [book on category theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375) which covers adjoints. Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician" is a standard reference, but I found it too difficult when I was first getting started - perhaps you will have a different experience, though.

---

As for your question:

If $F : C \to D$ and $G : D \to C$ are functors between categories $C$ and $D$, they are called an **Adjoint Pair** and we say $F$ is **Left Adjoint** to $G$ (resp. $G$ is **Right Adjoint** to $F$), written $F \dashv G$, iff

$$\text{Hom}_D(FX,Y) \cong \text{Hom}_C(X,GY)$$

(note $F$ is on the left side of the hom, and $G$ is on the right side).

An important motivating example is $- \times A \dashv (-)^A$, where the left is the cartesian product functor and the right is the set exponential functor. Here adjointness says

$$\text{Hom}(X \times A,Y) \cong \text{Hom}(X, Y^A)$$

In more pedestrian terms, this says there is a bijection between functions 
$f : X \times A \to Y$ and functions $\tilde{f} : X \to Y^A$. This bijection is given by partial application, if you are familiar with [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

---

Now, with this definition in mind, to show $\Delta : C \to C \times C$ is left adjoint to $\times : C \times C \to C$, we have to show

$$ \text{Hom}_{C \times C}(\Delta X, (A,B)) \cong \text{Hom}_C(X, A \times B)$$

By the definition of $\Delta$, this is

$$ \text{Hom}_{C \times C}((X,X), (A,B)) \cong \text{Hom}_C(X, A \times B)$$

But an arrow from $(X,X) \to (A,B)$ is exactly a pair of arrows - one $X \to A$ and one $X \to B$ (cf. the definition of [product category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category)).

But the universal property of products says exactly that such pairs of arrows are in bijective correspondence with arrows $X \to A \times B$. As needed.

Can you modify this proof to show the coproduct functor is *left* adjoint to $\Delta$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^